# Optimization: Minimize number of meetings

Tags: algorithm, optimization

This is an interview question

> There is an airline company that wants to provide new updates to all of its flight
>       attendants through meetings. Each ith flight attendant has a working time from start 
>       time `i (si)` to end time `i (ei)`. Design an algorithm that minimizes the number of 
>       meetings that company has to hold.

My approach is to pick a flight attendant who has the smallest end time. Then delete all those attendants whose start time <= this end time (because they already know the updates from the meeting). Continue until there is no more flight attendant to select. The airline should hold meetings at the end time of those attendants that I pick.

Is this a correct approach? If so, how to prove its correctness.

I think the complexity is O (n log n) since I will first sort the list in ascending order of end time and go through the list once.

Comment: Please be a little more specific on the problem; so any meeting reaches all the attendants who are working at the time the meeting takes place? Your estimation of runtime complexity is correct for the algorithm you describe, however.

Comment: If you pick the flight attendant with the earliest *start* time instead and hold the meeting ahead of that you can serve them all with one meeting.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: please clarify. have you just reversed the direction of the scan? that would also work, but not the way you described.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the point of the "working time", since they are flight attendants, aren't they in-flight during their working times? I assumed the meetings would need to be held outside of flights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my understanding, the described algorithm yields an optimal solution by the following argument. Fix an instance and its optimal solution; fix the earliest ending time `t` of a working period; if a meeting is scheduled to `t-1`, all working periods starting earlier than `t` can be served by this meeting, so any optimal solution using more than one meeting up to `t` could improved. On the other hand, there must be at least one meeting up to time `t-1` since otherwise some working periods could not be served.

After deletion of served working times, we obtain a smaller instance of the same problem. By using the above argument iteratively, a minimum number of meetings is obtained.

Comment: Thanks Codor for the answer.